# Use canvas.drawBitmap() to fill the screen

Tags: android, screen, textures

How can I fill the screen with texture? I can get screen size and density, also a bitmap size. But what next? should I transform texture with matrix or use special paint? Anything else? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
Bitmap background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap
     (YourBitmap, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, false);
```

Comment: Code is fine, but some explanation could be beneficial to new comers.

Comment: I agree with @Herbert.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a blank canvas, there's all kinds of things you can do with it! For example, to draw a bitmap, you could add the bitmap to res/drawable and do something like

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(caller.getResources(), r_bitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, draw_x - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), draw_y - (bitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
```

This is a typical operation to draw a background or a sprite. You can also use Canvas.drawText(), Canvas.drawRectangle(), Canvas.drawColor(). Lots of things.

I'm working on a game that uses Canvas as the main drawing surface, check out onDraw() [in my MainGamePanel class](https://github.com/iyulaev/tacotime/blob/master/src/com/yulaev/tacotime/MainGamePanel.java) and draw(Canvas) [in my GameItem class](https://github.com/iyulaev/tacotime/blob/master/src/com/yulaev/tacotime/gameobjects/GameItem.java) for some examples of drawing various bitmaps/shapes/colors to a Canvas. Just remember every time you draw, you will overwrite what's below it, so the order of operations definitely matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Use a SurfaceView.
- Create a Bitmap from the texture (.jpeg file) with the values you found eg. screen size.
- Draw that Bitmap to the canvas.

I hope this helps.